# How did Mal afford the Serenity?

Tags: firefly, serenity

We see Mal smitten with the Serenity in "*Out of Gas*". Clearly he has an eye for her, even as the used spaceship salesman tries to get him to buy a newer and marginally less crappy-looking ship.

Presumably even in used condition a spacegoing(ish) vessel isn't going to be *in*expensive. Where did Mal get the money needed to buy a ship?

Comment: I remember thinking he got a muster-out bonus after the browncoats were disbanded at the end of the war -- part of the forgiveness from the winners...

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefly/comments/z75qpf/how_did_mal_buy_serenity/ and http://www.fireflyfans.net/mthread.aspx?tid=24146 might be useful.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I saw those. Neither seem to have anything by way of evidence, just lots of guesswork.

Comment: @ZeissIkon - If you've got an iota of evidence of that, it would make a fine answer

Comment: If I had any evidence, I have made it an answer in the first place.